# core plot installation ios8

Tags: ios8, core-plot

I am trying to install Core Plot static library in my project. Here are some details

XCode Version:        6.0.1
Deployment Target(s): IOS7 and later
Language:             Objective-C

Is there a pre-compiled version of the library for this release?

Answer (score 0):

The latest [release package](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases) is 1.5.1. The precompiled release library should still work in Xcode 6.

Comment: Many thanks. I installed 1.5.1 in my project and it works great on my iphone6Plus and iphone5.